# MySQL table design / architecture, table is too big

Tags: mysql, database-design, sphinx

I have a MySQL DB that contains a lot of text, I'm fetching data from a website and inserting it into a table.

I'm using a SSD HD (100GB) for the DB and I'm out of space, I think that something in the table structure made it too big, I can't predict the size of all the columns so I'm using varchar\text\medium text for most of the fields. when I insert all the data to the DB I monitor the errors and when I see that a certain field is too small for the data I'm trying to insert I'm increasing the size of the field (e.g. from varchar(1000) to varchar(2000)).

until now I have about 1.8M~ rows, I think that I'm doing something wrong.

here is the structure of my table -

```
CREATE TABLE `PT` (
  `patID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IssueDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoFullText` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Abstract` text,
  `ForeignReferences` varchar(15000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrentUSClass` varchar(2200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OtherReferences` mediumtext,
  `ForeignPrio` varchar(900) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrentIntlClass` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppNum` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AppDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Assignee` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Inventors` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RelatedUSAppData` text,
  `PrimaryExaminer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssistantExaminer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AttorneyOrAgent` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReferencedBy` text,
  `AssigneeName` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssigneeState` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssigneeCity` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InventorsName` varchar(800) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InventorsState` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InventorsCity` varchar(800) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Claims` mediumtext,
  `Description` mediumtext,
  `InsertionTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LastUpdatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `patID_UNIQUE` (`patID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

what should I do? I have about 20% of the data (which means I'm going to need 350GB~ space) what is the performance impact here? should I divide the table into several tables over several HDs? I'm going to use sphinx to index and query the data in the end.

Comment: It's not the table structure, it's the amount of data you have. Your table structure uses varchars and text-type columns mostly, they work by storing the text and using 1 byte (or 2 bytes) appended at the end to make a note about the size of the text. That means that varchar(1500) is the same as using mediumtext column. The other thing that might be the problem is how MyISAM handles data storage and how it fragments the table space - I am no expert there but your table structure can't be "optimized" if you need that much text stored.

Comment: most of the big chunks of text are stored in the mediumtext\text columns, where can I see the files that save the text\mediumtext? should I consider using other DB engine?

Comment: [Refer to MyISAM internals](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_MyISAM).

Comment: You can try and check TokuDB MySQL engine which has much higher data-compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the non-TEXT column values are stored in one 8KB record (undivided unit of space on your HDD). TEXT column values are stored as pointers to external blocks of data.

These kinds of structures (very text oriented) are better handled by NOSQL (Not Only SQL) databases like MongoDB.

But I suspect that there are a lot of things you could do regarding how to handle & structure your data in order to avoid saving huge chunks of text.

The process of structuring a database to avoid repetitious information and to allow for easy updates (update in one place - visible everywhere) is called normalization.

If the data you're storing in those big VARCHARs (ex.: Inventors length 1500) is structured as multiple elements of data (ex.: names of inventors separated by a coma) then you can restructure your DB table by creating an inventors table and referencing to it.